# Why is my Python import of fcntl showing unresolved import?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, python-import

I created a virtualenv on CentOS 7.2, Python 2.7.5, Eclipse Neon (Luna does the same, btw), latest PyDev. I have a simple module that imports fcntl but PyDev shows it as unresolved. Tried reloading, refreshing project, clearing Python error markers, nothing makes the error go away. I can actually print the help for the module by running it like this so it is able to be called:

```
import fcntl
import hashlib

print help(fcntl)
```

Eclipse console shows:

```
Help on module fcntl:

NAME
    fcntl

FILE
    /home/mpetronic/.virtualenvs/quasar/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/fcntlmodule.so

DESCRIPTION
    This module performs file control and I/O control on file 
    descriptors.  It is an interface to the fcntl() and ioctl() Unix
    routines.  File descriptors can be obtained with the fileno() method of
    a file or socket object.
```

If I F3 on the module name in the import statement, I get:

[image]

So, it seems that under the hood, PyDev definitely knows where this module is and can call it, so the code works. It is just annoying to not be able to clear this warning:

[image]

Comment: This issue is not a duplicate as noted. Reinstalling the Python interpreter has not effect. The module "fcntl" is already on my PYTHONPATH. The path is clearly being resolved because the code works. So, this appears to be some quirk in PyDev that known work arounds are not solving.

Comment: The solution was to use "from fcntlmodule import fcntl"